# how to display image in imageview after captured using surfaceview class in android

Tags: android, android-camera

i have code that capture the image using custom camera API, the problem is its not coming back to preview mode, main thing is i want display the  captured image in imageview"

**this is my code:**

CameraPreview.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusMoveCallback;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    // Constructor that obtains context and camera
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            Camera.Parameters prams = mCamera.getParameters();
            prams.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

            mCamera.setParameters(prams);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.autoFocus(null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }
    }@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
            int width, int height) {





        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
        }
    }
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private Button captureButton;
    private ImageView showImageView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        ImageView showImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);


        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });

    }
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btns"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btns"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#ccc" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/backeff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Kindly try the below code..

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private Button captureButton;
    private ImageView showImageView;
    protected String imageFilePath;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_view);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        showImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    /** The jpeg callback. */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                File miDirs = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myphotos");
                if (!miDirs.exists())
                    miDirs.mkdirs();

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                String new_Date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
                        + ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1) + "-"
                        + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR)
                        + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-"
                        + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                imageFilePath = String.format(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myphotos"
                                + "/%s.jpg", "te1t(" + new_Date + ")");

                Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(imageFilePath);
                File file = new File(imageFilePath);
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();

                if (path != null) {
                    if (path.startsWith("content")) {
                        bitmap = decodeStrem(file, selectedImage,
                                CameraActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = decodeFile(file, 10);
                    }
                }
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,
                            "Picture Captured Successfully:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,
                            "Failed to Capture the picture. kindly Try Again:",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }

    };

    /**
     * Decode strem.
     * 
     * @param fil
     *            the fil
     * @param selectedImage
     *            the selected image
     * @param mContext
     *            the m context
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeStrem(File fil, Uri selectedImage,
            Context mContext) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(selectedImage));

            final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = getThumbSize(bitmap);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE,
                    THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos
                    .toByteArray()));

            return bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, fil.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Rotate image.
     * 
     * @param bmp
     *            the bmp
     * @param imageUrl
     *            the image url
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap rotateImages(Bitmap bmp, String imageUrl) {
        if (bmp != null) {
            ExifInterface ei;
            int orientation = 0;
            try {
                ei = new ExifInterface(imageUrl);
                orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();
            int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmpWidth,
                    bmpHeight, matrix, true);
            return resizedBitmap;
        } else {
            return bmp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decode file.
     * 
     * @param f
     *            the f
     * @param sampling
     *            the sampling
     * @param check
     *            the check
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int sampling) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()), null, o2);

            o2.inSampleSize = sampling;
            o2.inTempStorage = new byte[48 * 1024];

            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()), null, o2);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, f.getAbsolutePath());
            return bitmap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Rotate image.
     * 
     * @param bmp
     *            the bmp
     * @param imageUrl
     *            the image url
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bmp, String imageUrl) {
        if (bmp != null) {
            ExifInterface ei;
            int orientation = 0;
            try {
                ei = new ExifInterface(imageUrl);
                orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();
            int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmpWidth,
                    bmpHeight, matrix, true);
            return resizedBitmap;
        } else {
            return bmp;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Gets the thumb size.
     * 
     * @param bitmap
     *            the bitmap
     * @return the thumb size
     */
    public static int getThumbSize(Bitmap bitmap) {

        int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 250;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() < 300) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 250;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 600) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 500;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 1000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 750;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 2000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 1500;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 4000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 2000;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() > 4000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 2000;
        }
        return THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    }

}
```

Let me know the if you have any queries..

Comment: i checked the code dude its works really awesome thanks one problem is once i take pic it shoes in imageView after that its not coming to preview display please tell me how to dot it

Comment: If you want a preview then you have to create a imageview in the place of surface view and hide the surfaceview.. or else you can show the image in pop up dialog while clicking the image from bottom. Kindly try the above steps.. kindly up my answer..

Comment: my problem is when i click imageView it popups the gallery selection after chooese the gallery app its no showing image, it just opens gallery app  this is method i used for open gallery [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942015/how-to-open-image-when-i-click-the-imageview-in-custom-camera-app-in-android)

Comment: Use this Code to open the front camera..                            for (int camNo = 0; camNo < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); camNo++) {
     CameraInfo camInfo = new CameraInfo();
     Camera.getCameraInfo(camNo, camInfo);
     if (camInfo.facing == (Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)){
 mCamera = Camera.open(camNo);
     }
   }      Kindly up the last answer. so others will use it..

Comment: For open the image in pop up dialog.. You will have a path of the image, so you can create a imageview in popup dialog and load the image from the path. dont need gallery option..

Comment: replace this line camera = Camera.open(); and that code.. then check this if(camera==null) use the line camera = Camera.open();(open back camera)

Comment: i used that code u posted but its not preview even when i use `mCamera.startPreview();` at the end

Comment: Hi @Sivakumar . i checked your code and found an issue with it . for example you are showing the preview of camera on half screen and you took the image and save it . on preview it will show half image but when you open the image and see it , it will show you full image . even that part that was not in preview .